# Volume of $\cos(x)$ around y-axis using numerical integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Okay guys, so I have a question about numerical integration relating to the equation $y=\cos(x)$. The general equation is as follows:
$$\pi \int_0^{2 \pi } \left[\cos^{-1}(y)\right]^2 \, dy$$The problem being that I don't know how to square $\cos^{-1}(y)$, and then what to do from there. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "numerical integration" do you perhaps mean "definite integration"? And by the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ do you mean the integral of your function $f(y)$ with the relation $y=\cos(x)$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$? This is not what you've written - the way you've written it would be interpreted as the integral as $y$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: (You can write "$\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} f(y) dy$ with $y=\cos(x)$" to avoid confusion.)

Comment: Well, no. What I mean to say is that I'm supposed to use Simpson's Rule (S_N), but I understand that I wasn't very clear, sorry :/

Comment: Ah okay. But you do mean $x=0$ to $2\pi$ right? The inverse cosine of 2 pi is complex.

Comment: The textbook wants us to find the integral from x=0 to x=π/2. I was hoping to use the solution for x=0 to x=2π as as a guide.

Comment: I think that's a bad decision. Since $y=\cos(x)$ switches direction once on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, you're going to run into a bit of trouble using simpson's rule. You could split your integral into two intervals - $(0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,2\pi)$, on which $y$ goes from $1$ to $-1$ (first interval) and then from $-1$ back to $1$ (second interval).

Comment: That makes sense. So then how should I initially approach the square of arctan(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing with the discussion in the comments, in response to "how should I initially approach the square of arctan(x)?":

Nothing besides evaluating it! In the case from $0$ to $\pi$, you need to change the bounds of integration. $y$ goes from $\cos(0)=1$ to $\cos(\pi)=-1$, so you evaluate $\int_{1}^{-1} (\cos^{-1}y)^2 dy$, which involves evaluating $(\cos^{-1}1)^2$, $(\cos^{-1}0)^2$, and $(\cos^{-1}(-1))^2$. The result I get (using wikipedia's formula) is $-6.57974$, and the result I get using Mathematica is $-5.8696$  (from the command `Integrate[ArcCos[y]^2, {y, 1, -1}] // N`). The result is so innacurate, I figure, because of the curviness of the integration domain - you want to apply formulas like this on smoother/close to parabolic parts of curves.